# write.zoo still has row.names even without row.names set?

Tags: r

Consider this example: z is a simple dataframe to be written to a csv.

```
> z
        Date ID HH  
1 2018-01-01  1  4
2 2018-01-02  2  5
3 2018-01-03  3  6
> class(z)
[1] "data.frame"
> write.zoo(z, "z.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

The option "row.names=FALSE" is supposed to turn off row index "1,2,3". But it doesn't. The index is still in the csv file and if read back from the z.csv file by using date, it returned an error:

```
> zz <- read.zoo("z.csv", header=T, format="%Y-%m-%d")
Error in read.zoo("z.csv", header = T, format = "%Y-%m-%d") : 
  index has bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3
```

Is there anything wrong in write.zoo's syntax? How to get rid of the index? This is legacy code so it is easier to get write.zoo (or read.zoo) work than using other functions.

Comment: I want to keep the time index, i.e., 2018-01-01, etc. But don't want to see row index (or you called row names?), i.e., 1,2,3. So read.zoo should read back z.csv by using the time index. Am I wrong with the terminology? But anyway, the goal is to get rid of the row index 1,2,3 so that read.zoo can read back by %Y-%m-%d format.

Comment: > dput(z)
    structure(list(Date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2018-01-01", 
    "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03"), class = "factor"), ID = c(1, 2, 
    3), HH = c(4, 5, 6)), .Names = c("Date", "ID", "HH"), row.names = 
    c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: `z` is not a zoo object.

Comment: right, class(z) says it is a data.frame

Comment: `write.zoo` inputs a zoo object and outputs a data file just as `wite.table` inputs a data frame and outputs a data file.  Suggest you review `?write.zoo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `check.names = FALSE` to work around the issueusing an actual zoo object, i.e,

```
# install.packages(c("zoo"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(zoo)

z <- structure(c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("Date", "ID", "HH")), index = 1:3, class = "zoo")
z
#>   Date       ID HH
#> 1 2018-01-01 1  4 
#> 2 2018-01-02 2  5 
#> 3 2018-01-03 3  6 
class(z)
#> [1] "zoo"  

write.zoo(z, "Zoo_bar.csv")

z2 <- read.zoo("Zoo_bar.csv", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
z2
#>   Date       ID HH
#> 1 2018-01-01 1  4 
#> 2 2018-01-02 2  5 
#> 3 2018-01-03 3  6
```